# Rails Admin: Remove associated records option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-admin

I am implementing Rails Admin on my app and i would like to remove the option of seeing associated records. What i want to do is keep the option of adding a new record but not selecting a pre-existing one. The screen shot below shows what i am talking about:

[image]

I want to keep the product_variants field but with the only option of the button "Add new product variant"

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in way to do that. What i've done in the past is hide all records that are not associated.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  rails_admin do
    edit do
      field :product_variants do
        associated_collection_scope do
          inline_edit false

          associated_collection_scope do
            product = bindings[:object]

            proc { |scope| scope.where(product: product) }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm guessing the associations of course, but that should point you in the right direction.